# How to import own data for leave-one-out CV analysis scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I have 26 articles categorized into binary categories and I performed NB and 5-fold CV analyses. I imported my data with the `load_files()` command and I got this array:

```
target': array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]),
'target_names': ['negative', 'positive']
```

Even though I read LOO documentation and User Guide at scikit learn site I cannot grasp how to use my data. Here is the example from the site:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2])
loo = cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(2)
len(loo)
2
print(loo)
sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(n=2)
for train_index, test_index in loo:
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

For example, what does y stand for in the above example from the scikit learn site? Is it categories? What is train_index / test_index? Where does that come from?

Some help would be appreciated.

Regards,

guzdeh

UPDATE:

Thanks for reply, Brad. If I understand your answer I need to split my data into training / test set? I did that with my NB analysis (75:25), but with my 5-fold CV implementation, this split (80:20) was performed by the algorithm. This is my code (playing with 4 different classifiers):

```
def evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, K):
    # create a k-fold cross validation iterator of k=5 folds
    cv = KFold(len(y), K, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    # by default the score used is the one returned by score >>> method of the estimator (accuracy)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
    print scores
    print ("Mean score: {0:.3f} (+/-{1:.3f})").format(np.mean(scores), sem(scores))

clfs = [clf_1, clf_2, clf_3, clf_4]

for clf in clfs:
    evaluate_cross_validation(clf, bunch.data, bunch.target, 5)
```

`Bunch.data` are my articles loaded with `load_files()`, `bunch.target` are my two classes. So, if my thinking is correct, Leave-one-out being N-fold CV, then I could do the analysis with aforementioned code with K = number of articles?

However, I still do not understand what `y = np.array([1, 2])`  is in the example above and why train and test sets are needed since all articles but one is training set and one is test set.

Comment: Well let's start with a little clarification, you have a `target` array and a `target_names` array. What are your features? Where is that array? If I get your problem correctly you're trying to classify articles as either negative or positive. Without having information about the articles passed into the algorithm, there are no features to learn from. To put this another way, you have only `y` values (targets) and no `X` values (features).

Comment: After importing the articles I get the following array:  target': array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) and 'target_names': ['negative', 'positive']. This is used in my code, array is bunch.data and target names are bunch.target.

Answer (score 0):

So for these kinds of ML algorithms, you need to understand the difference in a "feature" a "target" and a "training set" and a "test set". It appears that there is only a target in your dataset. These would be the values you are attempting to predict. So in the case of this algorithm, `X_train` would have to be information about the articles, `y_train` would be the associated `negative` or `positive` value of the array you provided. `X_test` and `y_test` would be feature, target pairs that you use the algorithm to predict, and then score to estimate how effective your setup is.

Think of `features` like clues, there is a list of clues and you are trying to learn how to put those clues together to predict the `target`. Right now all you have are answers (target) without any clues, no learning can happen like that.

As far as the `index` goes, I would recommend using a library like Pandas to create dataframes with built in indices

http://pandas.pydata.org/

This is a little short on detail as there's not a ton to go on, but this should start putting you in the right direction.

Comment: No problem guzdeh, see my comment on your question. Splitting into training and testing sets is secondary to understand Features and Targets.